# ¿Como hacer una cookie en Spring boot que funcione tanto en navegador tipo chromium o en firefox?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, cookies

Escribí un código en Java para mantener persistente un checkbox en un sitio web, para ello uso ajax para enviar verdadero cuando el checkbox es chequeado o falso en caso contrario, generando una cookie en java que es devuelto en el response. El problema es que la cookie se genera y me funciona en `Chrome(versión 84.0.4147.105)`y en `Edge(versión 84.0.522.52)`. Pero ni siquiera se genera en Firefox, en el cual probé dos versiones distintas: `79.0` y `68.11.0esr`.

> HTML

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk01">Texto
</label>
```

> JavaScript y JQuery

```
var ischk = /*[[${ischk}]]*/ ''; // Traer desde java con thymeleaf
if(ischk) {
    $('#chk01').attr('checked', true);
}
            
$('#chk01').on('change', function() {
    var chk = false;
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        chk = true;
    }

    var parameter = {"val": chk};
    $.ajax({
        data: parameter,
        url: '/chequear',
        type: 'get'
    });
});
```

> Java (Controlador Spring boot)

```
@GetMapping("/chequear")
public String chequear(@RequestParam(name = "val", required = false, defaultValue = "false") String ischk, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("ischk", ischk);
    cookie.setMaxAge(7*24*60*60);
    cookie.setSecure(false); // Esta en falso para verlo en localhost
    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    
    model.addAttribute("ischk", ischk);
}
```

Espero alguien pueda darme luces al respecto, gracias por tu atención.